# How To Move Antique Chairs Across Country

Tags: moving

My aunt in California wants my grandmother's 2 antique wooden chairs, and I want them out of the house! I'm in Maryland, and it seems to be up to me to figure out the cheapest way of getting them to her. They're very heavy, around 30 pounds each.

I got a quote from UPS, but I'm wondering if there's any kind of organization out there where people pool together to share a moving truck, or you can buy space on a group pallet, or anything like that??
Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Hi Nicole, Welcome to Lifehacks. Please review the [Tour] and the [Help] for getting the most from our site where we look for out-of-the-box solutions to problems.

Comment: No matter how, or where, you wish to ship your treasure, it will have to be appropriately packaged/crated. First, you must find/or make a container for each chair. Weight is a secondary consideration after package dimensions. Providing the containers may be more expensive than moving them.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one "service" similar to what you describe. It's called [UShip](https://www.uship.com/) and is a resource for people who have room on a truck or other carrying vehicle to connect with those who have unusual, bulky, or otherwise unique items to be transported.

I've used it in the past and the prices are what I would consider reasonable compared to the major carriers. One benefit of this resource is that one puts up a shipment for bids and the carrier parties place bids to earn your business.

The item description is required, photos are recommended and a timeline presents to the prospective carrier the difficulty of the shipment. If one is flexible, one may find less expensive options than a shipment that has to be delivered the day before yesterday. For that, you'd have to use Einstein Air, a comedy skit from many years ago.